# Dynamically adding textbox value to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I want to dynamically create XML file with nodes of the all TextBoxes in the form with theirs values.

Example:

```
  var xmlNode =
       new XElement("TextBoxes",
                    new XElement("TextBox",
                        new XElement("name", textBox1.Name.ToString())
                    )
```

I've tried:

```
foreach (TextBox text in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            var xmlNode =
            new XElement("TextBoxes",
                    new XElement("TextBox",
                        new XElement("name", text.Name.ToString())
                    )
                );

            xmlNode.Save("Test.xml"); 
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your solution not working ? Do you get an exception ?

Comment: It is working but it's writing in XML only one TexBox value, just the first texbox.

Comment: try moving the Save out of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a file for each textbox instead of one file with all the textbox values. So start by declaring your xmlNode outside of the loop and saving it afterwards :

```
var xmlNode = new XElement("TextBoxes");
foreach (TextBox text in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        xmlNode.Add(new XElement("TextBox",
                    new XElement("name", text.Name.ToString())
                )
            );
    }  
xmlNode.Save("Test.xml");
```